# Updating an entity through Doctrine while it's persisted by a backend process

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, backend, entitymanager

I've got an issue with Doctrine being somehow nasty with automagical tracking of entities and changes. I've got a `UserManager` which gets data for a new user from a form and sends the data to the backend which creates the corresponding database entries. As the backend is only inserting some basic data like username, I want to persist everything else like a collection of user roles given through the form.

So my method should look like this:

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    $this->createUserInBackend($user);
    $this->em->merge($user);
    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

My issue now is that Doctrine either drops the data from the given `$user` and replaces it with the database content. This way I lose the chosen user roles. Without the `merge()` Doctrine tries an `INSERT` which is clearly not what I want.

I tried everything coming to my mind from fetching a managed copy before the merge, cloning or whatever. In all cases the objects are linked so I lose the data from the form (although their spl_object_hash differ).

Some more simplified details as requested:

```
class User
{
    // Username is tracked by backend
    private $username;

    // Fullname is only tracked by frontend/Doctrine
    private $fullname;
}
```

Variant 1:

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    // The user entity gets passed to the backend, which does some stuff
    // and also inserts the entity in the database.
    $this->createUserInBackend($user);
    // The entitiy is in the database, but not managed by the EM.
    // Therefore Doctrine does an INSERT.
    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Variant 2:

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    // The user entity gets passed to the backend, which does some stuff
    // and also inserts the entity in the database.
    $this->createUserInBackend($user);
    // Now there's an entity in the db with ID and username, but not the fullname 
    $user = $this->em->merge($user);
    // The merge finds the entry in the database and refreshes its data.
    // This leads to $user->fullname which was given in the form to be emptied. :(
    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

I also tried to put the return value from `merge` into an `$otherUser` variable, but the objects are linked and `fullname` still gets dropped.

I'd just need something to tell Doctrine that the new entity is managed, but it should not touch its data. I've looked into the underlying `UnitOfWork`, but couldn't find a trick to solve this.

Comment: So basically your collection of roles entities isn't being persisted ? Can we see the relationship you've set up between your User / Role entities ? And the UserType would help too.

Comment: I'll update my questions with some more details as soon as I'm back in the office and once I'm no longer pissed off by Doctrine ;)... but the issue isn't related to the association of roles. The entity is also loosing any scalar data which isn't handled by the backend.

Comment: I extended my post to clarify my issue and what I tried already.